# Nothing, when trying to echo SQL row?

Tags: php, mysql

So I managed to connect mysql database with my website and I tried to echo a row value, but when I do that I get completely nothing, not even an error, just a blank spot.

```
//GET CITY RESOURCES

$query = "SELECT lumber, clay, iron, crop FROM resources WHERE id = '$cityresourcesid'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);


$lumber = $row['lumber'];
$clay = $row['clay'];
$iron = $row['iron'];
$crop = $row['crop'];
```

Then I try to echo it, on the page.

```
<div class="resources">
    <h3>Production per hour:</h3>
    <?php
        echo "Lumber: ".$lumber;
    ?>
</div>
```

And this is what I get: 
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGqhk.png)

Weird thing is that it didn't give me any errors? And when im writing this sentence the value in "lumber" column is 500.

Comment: the result is still the same (nothing)

Answer (score 0):

If your id `$cityresources` an integer you should't use   the quotes

```
"SELECT lumber, clay, iron, crop FROM resources WHERE id =$cityresourcesid";
```

and for debug be sure you have a proper value in `$row` using `var_dump($row);`

if you not have a proper result  check for you data in db